# how to make the content of a page change according to a menu option?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a Dashboard that has a menu. Let's take the attached menu as an example (which is NOT mine, I took a snapshot from a video).

Could you give me an idea of how I can do so that when pressing an option from the side menu, the content on the right side changes. Should I create an html document for each possible option and reference it from an "a href tag" or is there some other way to do it? Preferably the solution or idea does not involve react, angular or vue.

[image: Example]

Comment: _One_ way (of many possibilities) is as you say an html document for each of the pages, loaded into an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) — you could change the `src` of the iframe using javascript when each different item is clicked. This may not be the best place to get advice as there is no definitive answer, and it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: take a look at this https://barba.js.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any of SPA (Single page Application) then you must have to go for multipage activities where you need `href` on each option given in your main menu.